# Is there such a thing as a permutation test for unequal sized time-series

Tags: time-series, t-test, permutation-test

The thing I like most about the permutation test is that it is intuitive, but I am not sure if it works in my case as independence would be hard to assume.

I a have data collected over a period of 10 weeks each day for a "pre-period" and data collected over a period of another 10 weeks (sometimes the next 10 weeks and sometime the next 10 weeks of next year) "post-period".

The pre-period is the control and the post-period is test receiving marketing.

The data would have the following structure

```
day   is_pre_period  units_sold_per_store
---  -------------- ----------------------
1     1               20
1     0               21
2     1               22
2     0               25
3     1               23
3     0               24
4     1               24
4     0               25
```

The goal is to see if there is a significant difference between the per-period and the post period. The problem I see is that:

1. This is a time-series. I would expect this data to be a random-walk, not independent.
2. Sometimes the groups are unequal sizes. The pre-period may be 10 weeks and the post-period may be 13 weeks.
3. Usually we have a pre and post period for one year and try to control for variation in the post period by collected data on the per and post period of the previous year. For example if our pre-post was in 2016 we would also like to know the pre-post of 2015 year. Maybe the weeks of the post-period (for example weeks 20-30 of 2016 and 2015) are always higher than the previous 10 weeks despite our marketing.

I would like to use a variation of the permutation test, but I am curious to know if there is any permutation test that handles this kind of data.

Comment: I am not sure whether a permutation test is applicable here.  But I want to point out that permutation tests require exchangeability which  includes situations where independence does not apply.

Comment: It is not clear to me what hypothesis you are testing. Are you trying to compare two time series "pre-period" vs "post-period"?

Comment: Sorry, the purpose is to see if the mean sales between pre and post are different. $H_0:$ there is no difference, $H_1:$ There is a difference between the mean 'units sold per store'.